# rm option to fail on nonexistent files

Tags: rm, safety

The `man` page of `rm` in GNU coreutils 8.12.197-032bb describes the `-f` or `--force` option as "ignore nonexistent files, never prompt". Without this option, it will remove any existing files, never prompt, and return a non-zero exit code if any of the specified files did not exist. I'd like to **preserve the files if *any* of the specified files do not exist**. What is the easiest way to do this?

The use case is *safety*: If I'm trying to remove a file which doesn't exist, it could be because there's an invalid expectation (or plain bug) in the command. For example [the famous `rm -rf /usr /lib/nvidia-current/xorg/xorg`](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22rm+-rf+%2Fusr+%2Flib%2Fnvidia-current%2Fxorg%2Fxorg%22) could have been averted in many ways, one of them being such an option (obviously unless the user by some incredible coincidence had a `/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/xorg` directory), and another being to [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting). However, quotes aren't always enough. For example, consider `ssh host '/bin/rm some paths; /bin/bash foo.sh'` - If I had forgotten the semicolon or inserted pretty much any other symbol like colon or comma, it would have tried to remove `/bin/bash` and `~/foo.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this sort of thing:

```
mkdir DELETE && mv "some" "paths" DELETE && rm -rf DELETE
```

For a single path:

```
mv /some/path DELETE && rm -rf DELETE
```

Even better, type the `rm command` on a separate command line: `mv /some/path DELETE` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `rm -rf DELETE` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That way, the only `rm` command that makes it into your shell history is on a file called `DELETE`, so if you removed an old version of a file, you don't risk removing the new version by accidentally pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> the wrong number of times then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you want to automate a bit:

```
mv_to_DELETE () {
  mkdir DELETE &&
  mv -- "$@" DELETE/
}
mv_to_DELETE "some" "paths"
rm -rf DELETE
```

Comment: Nice! Now I just need to use `mktemp` and a trap to move the files back and delete the temporary directory if the `mv` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
paths=("some" "paths")
for path in "${paths[@]}"
do
    [ -e "$path" ] || exit 1
done
```

before each `rm` command is a lot more complicated for a beginner, and depends on Bash arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
for path in "some" "paths"
do
    [ -e "$path" ] || exit 1
done
```

is more portable, but means duplicating the list of paths in the loop and the `rm` command. And storing all the paths in the same string variable means that the script no longer supports any of the `IFS` characters in file names.